Can `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` and `SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy` be used at the same time?
I found a logback tutorial with this code:

To better understand these policies, let’s create an appender which makes use of a TimeBasedRollingPolicy and a SizeTriggeringPolicy:

<appender name="rollingFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory> 
        <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>3MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>[%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>


The TimeBasedRollingPolicy implements both a RollingPolicy and a TriggeringPolicy.
The example above configures the fileNamePattern attribute based on the day – which means the name of each file contains the current date, and also that the rollover will happen daily.
Notice how we’re limiting the log data here – maxHistory is set to a value of 30, alongside a totalSizeCap of 3GB – which means that the archived logs will be kept for the past 30 days, up to a maximum size of 3GB.
Finally, the SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy defined configures the rollover of the file whenever it reaches 3 MB. Of course that’s quite a low limit...

But when I refer to this code and set maxFileSize to 100KB, I find that only TimeBasedRollingPolicy is working and SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy is not.
After that I found a log4j answer.

Hence, your SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy gets ignored since TimeBasedRollingPolicy is configured above.

So, Can TimeBasedRollingPolicy and SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy be used at the same time?
